# replace words like this with entities it is referring to

Tags: nlp, nltk

I am new to natural language processing and I want to replace words like this with what it actually refers to:

An example would be:

**segment topic:** My brand new dell laptop

**Segment text:** I bought this laptop and its good

How do i

- detect that the segment is talking about a laptop
- replace the occurrence of this laptop with My brand new dell laptop  (especially in mutli topic documents)

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=anaphora+resolution ... Add [`nltk`](http://google.com/search?q=anaphora+resolution+nltk) as a search term for some very specific starting points.

Comment: You could have added it as an answer, you would have gotten points. Thanks for the pointer and your time :).

Comment: You should also take a look at a less linguistics more information retrieval task that is like `anaphora resolution`, try `entity linking` https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=entity+linking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is called as 'anaphora resolution problem'. I am working on the same thing right now. I searched for any package in NLTK which does this. But I couldn't get anything on that. So u might have to develop your own algorithm to get this done.

these links will help you

[Anaphora Resolution Algo](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/jair/pub/volume15/palomar01a-html/node9.html)

[Anaphora Resolution](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpeople.ucsc.edu%2F~abrsvn%2Fanaphora%2520resolution.ppt&ei=Nv5MUrV7xuqsB7b1gJAP&usg=AFQjCNEshp8gtJNoyoRkbVa4sEanY1m_bw&bvm=bv.53537100,d.bmk)

[Anaphora Resolution](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&ved=0CEsQFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdepts.washington.edu%2Fuwcl%2Ftwiki%2Fpub%2FMain%2FTrecGroup%2FAnaphoraResolution.doc&ei=Nv5MUrV7xuqsB7b1gJAP&usg=AFQjCNHKaPae-QzElagirYjEpyxx5ITxow&bvm=bv.53537100,d.bmk)

First of all get all the anaphors and antecedents from each sentence and then try to find out the match for each anaphors. Anaphors are the pronouns. Like in your example it is 'this' and antecedents is the noun to which it refers to. In your case it is 'dell laptop' or 'dell'. The resolution of an anaphor means finding what it is referring to

Comment: Hey if what you are working on is opensource may be we could collaborate ?

Comment: Sorry its not opensource. But we can share any material that can help each other. :)